# Should I remove my comment that became irrelevant after an edit?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, etiquette

Someone posted an incorrect answer, I pointed it out, they edited the answer so it is now correct and my comment is no longer relevant.

What is the etiquette: should I remove my comment or post a new one saying "Ok it works now"?

Comment: Why would you hesitate to remove the comment after the OP of the answer corrected it, when you recognize it is no longer relevant?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, remove your comment. Comments are temporary [by design](/help/privileges/comment) and when they have been addressed, they should be removed.

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

Once you do that, the author of the answer knows you're satisfied with the new solution. It is even conceivable that after updating their answer, they will [flag your comment as No Longer Needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and it might be deleted before you can do it yourself (don't worry, this doesn't carry any penalty for you at all).

Please don't post something like "Ok it works now"; upvote and/or accept the answer, which is the Stack Exchange way of saying something works/is useful.

Comment: And if you delete your comment after someone flags it, you get the satisfaction of giving the flagger(s) a helpful flag.

Comment: I agree with this and upvoted it.  But occasionally it may be the case that a user who had commented to point out an error in an answer may not return to it, or otherwise may not be cognizant of the fact that the answerer corrected the mistake.  I've always found it helpful when an answerer pings me, when I've made such a comment, to inform me that the answer has been corrected.  In such cases, I readily delete my comment and upvote when appropriate, whereas, had I not been "pinged", I may not have been aware of the correction.