# Can I remove comments that are now obsolete (superfluous)?

Tags: discussion, comments

A question is made.  An answer is given.  Comments are given on the answer and request the answer be changed. The answer gets changed and the back-and-forth comments are now superfluous (unnecessary).

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330317/should-i-remove-my-comment-that-became-irrelevant-after-an-edit) ([Should I remove my comment that became irrelevant after an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330317/should-i-remove-my-comment-that-became-irrelevant-after-an-edit)) makes it clear that the author of a comment can (and is encouraged) to remove comments that are no longer applicable to the answer.  Also, it could happen that one author removes a comment, but the other author does not.

My question is this.  *Is there a way to delete comments that are no longer appropriate?*

My rational is that while some comments do help the understanding of the answer and should remain other comments are superfluous and simply waste the time of the reader.

For example, [what http response code for rest service on put method when domain rules invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190945/what-http-response-code-for-rest-service-on-put-method-when-domain-rules-invalid)

Has the two comments:

- If you remove the reference to 500, I'll remove my downvote :-) –
- Fair enough - 500 is certainly the worst choice of the three. –

But the answer doesn't even mention 500 so both comments are unnecessary.

**(Q) Can I remove them? If so how?**

A search for How can I remove comments on meta did (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+can+I+remove+comments) did not give me an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Delete your comments
- Flag the others as no longer needed and a moderator will delete them for you